# Manga/Webtoon featuring fractured worlds seen through cracks in time

Tags: story-identification, manga

Basically this woman moves in to an apartment but the apartment was considered to have a ghost in it, turns out that that apartment overlays another apartment and  a man was living in that apartment as well but in a different fractured world that were seen through cracks in time or dimension. I remember it was off of Webtoon, probably four to five years ago.

Comment: Please help, I really am in need of this..

Comment: When did you read it?

Comment: I think four to five years ago...

Comment: Well, timeline fits the answer you got. Please tell us if it's right or wrong, via the Green Checkmark or a comment!

Answer (score 3):

This matches the plot of [Freaking Romance](https://m.webtoons.com/en/romance/freaking-romance/list?title_no=1467) by Snailords:

> A sexy supernatural story about being out on your own, finding your dream apartment and discovering that your new place is haunted by a handsome spectral stranger from another dimension. Sure, HE can’t see you and YOU can’t touch him, but who said every relationship starts out perfectly?